# controlling gstreamer source plugin's output rate

Tags: gstreamer

All,

I have a gstreamer source plugin, which reads a video frame from an avi file. It's connected to gstreamer's core tee and two queue elements to push the video frame to two video processing elements.These two video processing elements' output gets muxed by my mux plugin.

With tee and queue, currently my gstreamer source plugin keeps pushing almost 6-10 video frames to both queue - till the queues limit is filled I believe. What I want is to push only one video frame from my source plugin and wait for signal from my mux plugin for next frame.

Can someone guide how this can be achieved in gstreamer framework?

Thanks!
ARM

P.S. I tried using queue element's max-size-buffers property set to 1 and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the existing GStreamer muxers. Basically the rate control is done there by using GstCollectPads to wait for one buffer on every sinkpad and then block, and once every sinkpad has a buffer you mux them together (properly synchronizing them relative to each other) and then forward the data. So rate control is done by blocking inside the muxer, and only once the muxer unblocks (i.e. consumes a buffer) a new buffer can be pushed on that sinkpad.

The queues in front of the muxer are irrelevant for that, but if you want to keep memory usage low you can use max-size-buffers=1 or similar settings.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your answer! The behavior of reading 6-10 frames from avi and pushing to both queues is happening before the first video frame buffer reaches to my mux. So, I do not understand how blocking at the mux level will help slow down the frame pushing from my source plugin.

Comment: It's going to slow down the frame pushing from the source plugin from the time until the queues are full. Then the source is blocked until the queue has space for another buffer, and there's always space for another buffer when your muxer consumed a buffer.

You could also just not use queues if your two source pipeline parts are independent of each other, or max-size-buffers=1 on the queue should do it too. You say it doesn't, but maybe that's a problem elsewhere.

Can you provide some code?

Comment: Sure. I will email the code so you can reproduce. please provide me your email. FYI.. max-size-buffers=1 does not work as expected as per my understanding. the queue should block its sink pad once it gets the first buffer thus the source plugin blocks too. what I see, it buffers at least 3 buffers with max-size-buffers=1 setting before blocking.

Comment: That would mean that the queue forwards buffers downstream. With max-size-buffers=1 it can only hold a single buffer. You can find my mail address on http://coaxion.net